# How can I search string value from database and show in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I want to search value from database  and delete value from databaseshow. I can Search and but when I click the delete button its give me the following Error:

> Syntex error:missing operand after '='.

Here is my code:

```
private void sID_textBox7_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dataGridView4.DataSource;
                bs.Filter = "[Product ID]=" + sID_textBox7.Text.ToString();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your filter will be like `Product ID = SomeText` which is not right. You need to use it like  `Product ID = 'SomeText'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just missed the `'` before and after the filter value.

`[Product ID] = SomeText` should be `[Product ID] = 'SomeText'`

```
private void sID_textBox7_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView4.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = "[Product ID]=" + "'" + sID_textBox7.Text + "'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

See [BindingSource.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Writing `sID_textBox7.Text.ToString()` has no sens. `.Text` property returns a `String`, no need to use `.ToString()`.